# Calling class functions through list

Tags: python, function

I was attempting to place certain class variables within a list. Each class has a method known as update and considering they each do the exact same thing I though it would be allot more convenient to simply place them in a list and call the method that way.

The method I am trying to call is known as update and this is the error that I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\GoodPie\Desktop\New Game Dev\main.py", line 177, in <module>
    initialize_game()
  File "C:\Users\GoodPie\Desktop\New Game Dev\main.py", line 61, in initialize_game
    start_menu(debugging, screen, clock, image_cache)
  File "C:\Users\GoodPie\Desktop\New Game Dev\main.py", line 88, in __init__
    self.init_start_screen()
  File "C:\Users\GoodPie\Desktop\New Game Dev\main.py", line 115, in init_start_screen
    self.update_group.append[New_Game_Button, Load_Game_Button, Quit_Game_Button, Settings_Button]
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
```

Here is the code I am trying to use

Entities.py:

```
class Quit_Game_Button(Entity):

    def __init__(self, x, y, image_cache):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.image_cache = image_cache
        self.image = function.get_image("images/Quit_Game.png", self.image_cache)
        self.image.convert()
        self.rect = Rect(x, y, 150, 30)

    def update(self, mouse_position):
        if self.rect.collidepoint(mouse_position):
            self.image = function.get_image("images/Quit_Game_Hover.png", self.image_cache)
        else:
            self.image = function.get_image("images/Quit_Game.png", self.image_cache)

    def check_click(self, clicked, mouse_position):
        quit = False
        if self.rect.collidepoint(mouse_position):
            if clicked:
                quit = True
        return quit

class Settings_Button(Entity):

    def __init__(self, x, y, image_cache):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.image_cache = image_cache
        self.image = function.get_image("images/Settings_Button.png", self.image_cache)
        self.image.convert()
        self.rect = Rect(x, y, 50, 50)

    def update(self, mouse_position):
        if self.rect.collidepoint(mouse_position):
            self.image = function.get_image("images/Settings_Button_Hover.png", self.image_cache)
        else:
            self.image = function.get_image("images/Settings_Button.png", self.image_cache)
```

main.py

```
self.update_group.append[New_Game_Button, Load_Game_Button, Quit_Game_Button, Settings_Button]

mouse_position = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

#Updating Entities on the screen
for entity in self.update_group:
    entity.update(mouse_position)
```

Just so it's clear, the functions do exist. I was just wondering if I was going about calling methods the write way through a list/array? If not could someone please point me in the right direction? :)

Comment: How about some non-imaginary code?

Comment: That code wouldn't give that error. Please provide the actual code, plus the traceback.

Comment: I added the code I was actually using. I just thought it might be to long

Comment: You have the classes in the list and try to treat them like instances of themselves?

Comment: Please add the full traceback, not only one line.

Comment: And what is this error? *_*

Comment: You should read my answer. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue did not lie within the actual for loop for calling the update function within the class, it occurred through the appending off the class instances to the list. Therefore to solve this problem I tried:

```
self.update_group = [New_Game_Button, Load_Game_Button, Quit_Game_Button, Settings_Button]
```

and it worked perfectly. I don't know what the issue is with the appending to the array, but having a fixed list/array seems to work just fine for me. Credits to @Matthias for actually making me look at the method for adding the instances to the array.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple error.

```
self.update_group.append[New_Game_Button, Load_Game_Button, Quit_Game_Button, Settings_Button]
```

should be

```
self.update_group.extend([New_Game_Button, Load_Game_Button, Quit_Game_Button, Settings_Button])
```

You're trying to index `append` where you should call it. Second point is, that append takes only one parameter, so you should use `extend`.

But you're still operating on the classes, not instances of the classes.

Comment: hmm believe it or not that is what I had initially. But this returns the this error: `TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (4 given)` So i changed it to `self.update_group.append([New_Game_Button, Load_Game_Button, Quit_Game_Button, Settings_Button])` but that returned this error: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'update'`

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to assign `one` to `one(1)` and `two` to `two()`, that results in a `referenced before assignment` error So change the class Names to something more suitable like `One` and `Two`

Also It is *strictly* **[recommended](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names)**(for CapWords convention see pg4 [here](http://msdl.cs.mcgill.ca/people/shahla/misc/PythonConventions.pdf)) to always start a python class name with a uppercase character

Corrected code would look like: *(I've implemented the **str** method)*

```
class One:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def update(self):
        self.x += 1

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.x)

class Two:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def update(self):
        self.x += 1

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.x)

def test():
    one = One(1)
    two = Two(2)

    update_list = [one, two]

    for i in update_list:
        i.update()
        print i

test()
```

Output:

```
2
3
```